# Can't Activate Solution from Site Settings in SharePoint foundation 2010

Tags: deployment, sandbox-solution

I'm currently tasked with developing a branding solution for SharePoint Foundation sites. I've created a WSP file which can be deployed through my local machine through Visual Studios, but when I upload the solution into the Solution Gallery in site settings, I can't activate the solution. The solution was created as a sandboxed solution according to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg447066.aspx).

When I choose to activate from the RibbonMenu or the drop down for the solution, the resulting modal dialog has an activation button which is disabled. I'm logged in as the System Account, so I believe I have full permissions over the site collection.

What do I need to do in order to activate solutions from this gallery page?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Can you check that ou have enabled and configured the user code service on your farm and started it?

Look for user code service in service applications and create one if it is not there.

Then go to

Central Administration > System Settings > Manage Services on Server > check that  “Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service” service is running

Comment: Tiny correction: "Look for user code service in service applications" should be "Look for user code service in services".  Small distinction but possibly confusing for newbies.  There's no user code service application to create.  The Central Administration navigation progression is right though.

Comment: which server should it be enabled on? The WFE or the App Server? (For what it's worth, I enabled it everywhere and it seemed to work)

Comment: Small addition: In SharePoint 2013 the Windows service is called 'SharePoint User Code Host'.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this in SharePoint(2013) Central Administration/Application Management/Manage Services on Server by starting the Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service

Answer (score 0):

Central Administration ---> System Settings ---> Manage Services on Server ---> Start “Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service” on any of the servers in the farm.