# Install Document Library from an .stp template in a different site - Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, template

Let's say I have 2 sites in the same Sharepoint Environment, call them 'Site1' and 'Site2'. I have a Document Library in Site 1 which I saved as a DocLibSite1.stp template. I want to install the DocLibSite1.stp template in Site 2 so I tried 2 things.

1. Upload the DocLibSite1.stp file in the Site Settings / Solutions (under Web Designer Galleries) and add the Document Library as an App from the template. When going into the Create New App and searching for DocLibSite1 I am getting nothing.
2. Upload the DocLibSite1.stp file in the xxxxxx.sharepoint.com (root site) Site Setting / Solutions (under Web Designer Galleries) and again, tried to add the document library as an app from the template in Site 2. Again, when searching for DocLibSite1 I am getting nothing.

**Notes**:

- When creating a new app from Site 1 and searching for DocLibSite1, I can find it.
- When trying to Activate the solution from the Solutions (from either the root/site1 or site2), the Activate/DeActivate and Upgrade options are grayed out. [See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ag0A.jpg)
- When searching online I found this: [See link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12996/cant-activate-solution-from-site-settings-in-sharepoint-foundation-2010), but it seems to refer to a Server based Sharepoint Environment and not Online based.

Specific to Sharepoint online, I could not find anything.

Would appreciate help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I might be wrong as I use mainly on premise SP2010 and 2013 but I think you need to upload the stp file not the the 'Solutions' library but to the 'List Templates' (ie www.YoursiteURL/_catalogs/lt/Forms/AllItems.aspx)

Comment: I think you may be wrong here. It is not a list but a Document Library. Do I still need to add it to the List Templates?

Comment: So I actually tried this and it worked! You were not wrong after all. 
I uploaded the .stp in the List Template section and managed to move the document library from one location to another. Thank you (and choosing your answer as the correct one)

Comment: Glad I could help. With regards to your first comment in SharePoint Document Library is as well a list just with some additional features.

Answer (score 0):

1. you are getting DocLibSite1 when creating on new app so thats how SharePoint is taking your installed library. It is a custom app which is being created.
2. Second, I dont think you require activate and deactivate feature at this point for an stp file and that is why the options are disabled.

Comment: Yes but only on Site 1. I want to be able to install the template which I created from the document library on Site 1, on another Site, Site2, which is in the same Sharepoint Environment but is an entirely different site. So I tried to upload the .stp file in the Solutions of Site 2 and also the root site Solutions folder. But when trying to create an app from Site 2, I cannot see the 'DocLibSite1.stp' file to install the Document library from it!

Comment: Did you go through this? https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/victorbutuza/2014/09/08/list-saved-as-template-does-not-appear-under-add-an-app-or-what-lists-can-you-save-as-template-and-use-for-creating-other-lists-based-on-them/

Comment: Perhaps because the document library has a content type that is specific to that particular site, it doesn't give the option to add the Document Library to Site 2 as the content type make the document library dependant to Site 1. So I tried creating a document set and uploading 3 random files in it, and repeated the whole process but still I cant see the template when trying to create a new app.

Comment: you are right on Content type..check again..you are missing something again...just create a stp without any content and see if it comes.

Comment: probably the list type and definition is different

Comment: I tried with a new Document Library with no added extra settings, no content types, etc. Still I didn't manage. There must be something else.