# Activate command disabled in Solutions Gallery

Tags: 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, sandbox-solution, solution-deployment, minrole

Scenario: SharePoint 2016 MinRole Farm with 2 Servers.

I tried starting Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service in one and in both servers as I found this: [Can't Activate Solution from Site Settings in SharePoint foundation 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12996/cant-activate-solution-from-site-settings-in-sharepoint-foundation-2010/166487#166487) and used the PS cmd:

```
$SA = Get-SPServiceInstance | Where {$_.Id -like “*GUID*”}
$SA.Provision()
```

This made that service start on the servers but shown as Not compliant in Central Administration>Services on Server. Anyway, by having this service running, it didn't make a difference and the Activate button kept been disabled for a new solution (template.wsp) I uploaded to the Solution Gallery.

Can you advise how to make the Activate button Enabled?

Comment: what are the role of servers FE, App or?

Comment: 1 server: Application with Search and 1 server Front-End with Distributed Cache and I have SharePoint User Code Host Service running automatic under Services on both servers and Central Administration Services on Server is saying that is not Compliant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service compliant on the Front End, Front end with DC or Custom MinRole.

- If you have any of the above role in your farm then you can enable
  the auto provision and start the services from central.
- Also make sure that "SharePoint User Code Host" service is running on
  server (check via services on the computer)
- If the service is started and the Activate button is not yet active
  you will need to elevate the privileges In the WebApplication
  UserPolicy, add the Service Account used for Microsoft SharePoint
  Foundation Sandboxed Code Service with Full Control rights.

Read more here: [Enable Sandbox solutions on SharePoint 2016](http://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2016/08/14/enable-sandbox-solutions-on-sharepoint-2016/)

Comment: The account being used to run the service is the farm account, which has Full control and Full read on the WebApp User Policy. Service is running on both servers. I didn't understand your first point of "can enable the auto provision and start the services from central."

Comment: check the link, i shared

Comment: I carefully followed the steps in the link you shared. I autoprovisioned the service from CA and now the service is showing Compliant. I also changed the service account from the Farm account to the Services account which is another one with Full control permissions in the web app and also did that for the Windows service in the server, I restarted the service in Windows Server, restarted the service in Central Admin, everytime checking to see if the Activate btn will enable, but nothing helped. It is still greyed out and I can not enable my solution.

Comment: I even logged in with the system account in the solution gallery and with my admin account. Either way that option to Activate the solution keeps been disabled. Any other suggestion that might help me?

Comment: at this point, i would create a empty sandbox solution, and upload to brand new test site collection and test it if it is working on not? i am feeling either sharepoint site or sandbox solution may have an issue.....also i would try to open the site in different browser i.e chrome / Edge and see if the button option enabled

Comment: The Activate btn is enabled now and I tested with 3 browsers (IE, Chrome and Edge) and found that the issue is that as I am modifying an existing .wsp that is active as a solution in the site collection and saving as a template with a different name, when I download from my test farm to prod it is keeping the same solution id, so the issue is that I am having now 2 solutions, the original one and the modified one, both with the same solution id and that is why I can not see the activate btn enabled as the system thinks that it is the original one that is already activated.

Comment: that's great news, Glad finally it is working. Enjoy!

Comment: What will be the appropriate way to have the 2 solutions Activated and making SharePoint create a new solution id for the modified one? Is like having 2 versions of the same template activated.

Comment: Not sure about it, may be time to spin up a new questions and let Developer guru answer it. :) also if you think it is helpful, mark it as answer.